# Bubbling doesn't work, Sass injects the class inside of nested elements instead of around them when trying to use @mixin and @content

Tags: media-queries, sass

I am using `@content` within mixins to simplify Media Queries. If I use the first mixin within nested classes the output bubbles up and nests the classes. The second example doesn't work at all (no errors), the nesting doesn't seem to work properly.

**This works fine**

```
// Everything larger than a landscape tablet but less than or equal to the desktop

@mixin desktop-only {

    @media only screen and (min-width : $mq-tablet-landscape + 1) and (max-width : $mq-desktop) {
        @content;
    }

    .lt-ie9
    {
        @content;
    }
}
```

**This does not work**

```
@mixin ie8 {

    .lt-ie9
    {
        @content;
    }

}
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a useful explanation.  Does it make an error?  How does the output differ from what you expected it to be?

Comment: I updated the main question. There are no errors. It is just nesting the element that I want the other elements to be nested inside of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mixin looks like it works to me:

```
.foo {
    @include ie8 {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

The output is exactly as I would expect it to be:

```
.foo .lt-ie9 {
  color: red;
}
```

Since your question doesn't give any useful information as to why the mixin is wrong, I'm going to assume that what you *want* is to have the classes in the reverse order.  In which case, your mixin needs to be written like so:

```
@mixin ie8 {
    .lt-ie9 & {
        @content;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
.lt-ie9 .foo {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was trying to ask. Thanks.